# Extract part of URL with Google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So i have this url "https://www.site.be/pand/titel-van-het-pand-t8500-17082-4" and i have to extract the reference number at the back of the url. In this example "t8500-17082-4" with GTM to put into a custom dimension like this:

```
var dimensionValue = 'REFERENCE_CODE_HERE';
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
```

The reference codes at the eind of the url could start with either -t8... or t9...

Comment: What is the error or problem you are encountering?

Comment: If using GTM is not a requirement here you could just use `explode` twice here and accomplish what you want

Comment: @Adonis I tried to do this with Variable > type URL > component type URL fragment but with that i only can get fragments starting with # en other options aren't suitable for this problem. I only have acces via the Google Tag manager so no acces to the actual code of the site. I just don't know how to extract that 'reference code' from the url with simply GTM

Comment: @yanman1234 GTM is required but i will keep your tip in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In GTM go to "Variables" -> "NEW" -> "Custom JavaScript" and type:

```
function(){

  var myRegexp = /(-t8|-t9)(.*)/g; //assuming you only ever have one "-t8"/"-t9" in the URL
  var result = document.URL.match(myRegexp);
  if(result !== null){
    return result[0];
  }else{
    return null; //or whatever you want to return if the ID is not in the URL
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Matus,

Thanks for the quick answer! 

I'm just having this problem right now. I extracted the part from the URL with your code as a variable - custom javascript:

name: {{Google forum custom js}}


After defining the variable i connected the variable with the Analytics tag in GTM like this:

Index: 1 - dimension value: {{Google forum custom js}}

The tag extracts the part from the url but when i visit another url (other reference code) it overwrites the dimension for that session?

Comment: Yes, the custom dimension would be overwritten. What you can do is to save the value in a cookie or local storage? Then, instead of returning "null" you can return the value of the cookie/local storage. I am not sure about your setup, but you could also just not set the custom dimension if the fucntion returns null.