# Extract part of URL with Google tag manager using regex

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

i'm looking for something similar to: [Extract part of URL with Google tag manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590669/extract-part-of-url-with-google-tag-manager)

But with the difference in end of the url, where some ends with a / and some not.

My urls:

- /mobilabonnement/mobilabonnement-for-alle/smart-12-gb
  /mobilabonnement/mobilabonnement-for-alle/smart-12-gb/
  /mobilabonnement/mobilabonnement-for-ungdom/smart-ung-12-gb
  /mobilabonnement/mobilabonnement-for-ungdom/smart-ung-12-gb/

I'm trying to extract the "smart-12-gb" and "smart-ung-12-gb".

```
function(){

  var myRegexp = /(smart-|ung-|barn-)(.*)/g;
  var result = {{Updated Page Path}}.match(myRegexp);

  if(result !== null){
    result[0] = result[0].replace("/","");
    return result[0];
  }else{
    return null; 
  }
}
```

This function works, but i was wondering if it's possible to do it in one go, in regex?

Comment: Try `/\b(?:smart|ung|barn)-[^\/]*/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UlFP74/2).

Comment: See a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53390448/3832970) that does what you need: only extracts these values from the last subpart of a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If smart is at the beginning, you could make the `ung-` and `barn-` part optional and then match not a forward slash:

`\bsmart-(?:ung-|barn-)?[^\/]+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EHGdLe/1)

That will match:

- `\bsmart-` Match a word boundary `\b` followed by `smart-`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `ung-` Match  literally
  - `|` Or
  - `barn-` Match literally
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `[^\/]+` Match 1+ times not a forward slash using a negated character class

Answer (score 2):

To match these strings *at the end of the URL only* you need to use

```
/\/((?:smart|ung|barn)-[^\/]*)\/?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UlFP74/3)

Your function will look like

```
function(){
  var myRegexp = /\/((?:smart|ung|barn)-[^\/]*)\/?$/;
  var result = {{Updated Page Path}}.match(myRegexp);
  return result ? result[1] : null; 
}
```

**Pattern details**

- `\/` - a backslash
- `((?:smart|ung|barn)-[^\/]*)` - Group 1: `smart`, `ung` or `barn`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\/?` - 1 or 0 backslashes
- `$` - end of string.