# Capture and Remove URL segment in custom JS - GTM

Tags: javascript, regex, e-commerce, analytics, google-tag-manager

I need a custom JS variable for GTM that excludes everything from "/p/" until the end or the next "/", what happens first.

The url after the /p/ can be anything, any length, and have nothing afterwards.

Before:

- hostname/category/brand/some-snicker-model/p/NIBQ5448001
- hostname/campaign/some-snicker-model/p/AB434222/?device=type

After:

- hostname/category/brand/some-snicker-model
- hostname/campaign/some-snicker-model/?device=type

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should works:

```
/\/p\/.*?(?=(\/|\?|$))/g
```

---

```js
const data = ["hostname/category/brand/some-snicker-model/p/NIBQ5448001", "hostname/campaign/some-snicker-model/p/AB434222/?device=type"]

const regex = /\/p\/.*?(?=(\/|\?|$))/g;

data.forEach(url => {
    console.log(url.replace(regex, ''))
})
// hostname/category/brand/some-snicker-model
// hostname/campaign/some-snicker-model/?device=type
```

---

Another better alternative would be to use [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), as it allows to separate the url according to the origin, the path name, the search value, etc.

```js
let data = [
    'https://www.hostname.com/category/brand/some-snicker-model/p/NIBQ5448001',
    'https://www.hostname.com/campaign/some-snicker-model/p/AB434222/?device=type',
    'https://www.hostname.com/category/brand/some-snicker-model/p/NIBQ5448001?device=mobile'
];

let pattern = /\/p\/.*?(?=(\/|$))/g;
data.forEach(element => {
    let url = new URL(element);
    let new_url = url.origin + url.pathname.replace(pattern, '') + url.search
    console.log(new_url)
});
```

Comment: What about this URL? hostname/category/brand/some-snicker-model/p/NIBQ5448001?device=mobile
It looks like it extracts the parameters as well: https://regex101.com/r/UlFP74/6

Comment: You said ``until the end or the next "/"``. Is it normal that there is no ``/`` before ``?device=`` ?

Comment: Yep. Checked and it happens.

I'm trying to get this into a custom JS, following this guide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389765/extract-part-of-url-with-google-tag-manager-using-regex

but can't make it work. Maybe the {{Updated Page Path}} should be a URL type?

Comment: I updated my post with a more efficient way to remove /p/... keeping the parameter correctly.

Comment: I see it works, **thank you**.
I'm having a lot of problems turning this into a GTM variable. There's basic syntax I don't know and the arrow is not supported.