# Capturing a part of a URL in Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, regex, google-tag-manager

Struggling to figure this one out. I'm wanting to capture the end part of a click URL as a variable in Tag Manager (www.testsite.com.au/insert-nameofproduct-here-abc1234).

In the example, I'm wanting to capture the abc1234 bit as its a product code for a website Im working on which has a LOT of those. And the reason for wanting to capture this bit of info is so that I can pass it through GA as an event label for example:

Event Category: Product 
Event Action: Select
Event Label: abc123

Now after testing the regex ([a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}$), that worked in all the regex testers. But when I try and raise it in Tag Manager as a URL variable as full URL, the variable doesn't pass through.

Care to help me out on this one? My javascript is superrusty so Im drawing a blank after function

Comment: Can you add the code that is not working. Will help to see how you are declaring etc.

Comment: @PaulThomas - haven't gotten to that stage yet. I was going down the route of creating a custom variable with the variable type being URL and component type being path and entering in the regex followed by Click Classes as the URL Source

Comment: Does it need to be a custom variable, or could you just alter the url? See here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Comment: @PaulThomas trying to achieve this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590669/extract-part-of-url-with-google-tag-manager) but I keep getting nothing

Comment: Ok, I tweaked the function for that post with the regex you need and it worked fine. I wont post here as I dont feel it will help others. But you can look and copy. https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/AdmirableUnrealisticMacro look in the script.js hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need a custom javascript valiable

```
function () {
  return {{Click URL}}.match(/[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}$/) ? {{Click URL}}.match(/[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}$/)[0] : null

}
```